# nginx + php5-fpm.sock is not found

Tags: php, sockets, nginx

I have several subdomains, each with a socket:

**In /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/album.conf ::**

```
user = album
group = album
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-album.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
```

**In /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf ::**

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

**In /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ::**

```
upstream php5-fpm-album-sock {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-album.sock;
}

server {
            ## Escucha en el puerto 80 (HTTP)
            listen 80;

            ## Raíz donde se encuentra la página Web
            root /srv/www/album/;

            ## Orden de prioridad de los archivos index
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            server_name album.bichomen.com;
            access_log /srv/www/album/access.log;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                   root /srv/www/album;
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                   fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-album-sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
                   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include fastcgi_params;
            }
    }
```

The problem is to disbelieve the socket in **/var/run/**

**Error in nginx.log:**

```
1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-album.sock failed 
(2: No such file or directory)
```

Where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: `ls -lah /var/run` returns what and does it list the socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end restart the server and it works.

Answer (score 0):

ls -lah /var/run

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb 28  2015 /var/run -> /run
```

I have created the directory php5-fpm:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 40 May 24 14:52 php5-fpm
```

and I have modified the configuration files:

```
unix server: /var/run/php5-fpm/album.sock;
```

Answer (score -1):

1. change the php5-fpm.sock to php-fpm.sock
2. restart the php-fpm service
3. restart the nginx service

Comment: dont just change things at random. you don't even know if that file exists.